# Polymer 1.0 on firefox ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined

Tags: firefox, polymer, web-component, polyfills, html-imports

Hello I have a working Polymer 1.0 web page on Chrome and Opera. Now I need the page to run in Firefox and Safari. I have the following test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'); ?>
        <link rel="import" href="<?= Router::url('/'); ?>bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

        <dom-module id="test-element">
            <template >
                <h1>It works</h1>
            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer({
                    is: "test-element"
                });
            </script>
        </dom-module>
    </head>
    <body unresolved>
        <test-element></test-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js'); ?>
```

I thought the Polyfills of webcomponents would take care of the html import. But it's not working. In firefox I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
```

I haven't been able to test it with Safari but I expect a similar result.

Am I doing anything wrong? how can I make this work?

Also I tried deleting the webcomponents and runing bower update to install them again.

thank you

EDIT:

I have two files. index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>
        <?php echo $this->Html->script('/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js'); ?>
        <link rel="import" href="<?= Router::url('/'); ?>bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
        <?=  $this->element('Polymer/test-element');?>
    </head>
    <body unresolved>
        <test-element></test-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the element file:

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <template >
        <h1>It works</h1>
    </template>
    <script>
        addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            Polymer({
                is: "test-element"
            });
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

This works fine. My problem is if I delete the addEventListener. The Firefox gets the same error:

```
ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
```

As if Polyfills were not loaded in time. Is there a way to fix this? Is adding the addEventListener the right way to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try wrapping your javascript under addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {}).

```
addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            Polymer({
                is: "test-element"
            });
})
```

This will ensure the webcomponents polyfill is completed for browsers that do not support it. If the element is imported using html import then the event listener is not required. Please refer to https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready for more details.

**Response for the edit:**
import polymer.html in your test-element file and 'remove' it from your index.html file. The best approach is to define an elements.html file, import all your elements (including test-element) into your elements.html file and import elements.html file into your index.html file. Also in each of your elements file (like test-element.html) make sure you import all the dependencies. I would suggest you to start with polymer-starter-kit

Comment: Nice! what if I have several Polymer elements in different files? would you implement this callback function in every polymer element? inside the js?

Comment: If you are importing an element using html import, then event listener is not required. The script in your index.html might run even before the polyfill is completed and hence event listener for completion of polyfill is required. The html import will work only after the polyfill is completed, so the elements inside your html import will have no issues.

Comment: It works adding it inside the dome-module. Now, you say is "This is required only in index.html file and for non-chrome browsers." How can I handle that it runs only when browser needs it?

Comment: You can have the event listener in chorme browser and it will work. I was just trying to make the point that the webcomponents polyfill should complete for non-chrome browsers. This event listener is fired even for chrome browser, so no issues.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I have edited my question. Could you please take a look? thank you again!

Comment: try import polymer.html in your test-element file and 'remove' it from your index.html file. The best approach is to define an elements.html file, import test-element into your elements.html file and import elements.html file into your index.html file. I would suggest you to start with polymer-starter-kit.

Comment: Not working without the event listener. Tested everything just not working :( thank you though

Comment: Here is a reference solution without event listener and works in firefox. http://plnkr.co/edit/13QJ7QFETIBg4bEiCMS7?p=preview