# TypeError: grid.columns[0] is undefined in Firefox Vaadin Grid

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, vaadin-grid, vaadin-elements

I am usign vaadin grid. I get:

> TypeError: grid.columns[0] is undefined

In Firefox  as in the title. In Chrome it is working. The code:

```
var grid = grid || document.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    var json = '[["Blabla", true, "sdfsdfsd", "fsdsdfsdfsd fsdfds fsdf shfskd hds", 0, "39acbfa4-6d6b-4af9-b872-03fc70328183"]]';

    var testJSON = JSON.parse(json);
    grid.items = testJSON;

    // --> ERROR: undefined in firefox
    grid.columns[0].renderer = function(cell) {
        //...
    };    
});
```

Why?

Comment: use console.log and try to get the value of grid just before you are getting error

Comment: I did a console.log just after grid.items = testJSON; It shows the vaadin grid...: <vaadin-grid style="min-height: 25em;" frozen-columns="0" class="vaadin-grid-loading x-scope vaadin-grid-0"> ...

Comment: @TieroL. The `json` variable doesn't contain a valid JSON string. How does that even get past `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: It does. This is typo3 fluid (php) ---> A json array is generated like: [[ "Blabla", true, "sdfsdfsd", "fsdsdfsdfsd fsdfds fsdf shfskd hds …", 0, "39acbfa4-6d6b-4af9-b872-03fc70328183" ]]

Comment: I removed the typo3 fluid stuff, so it is maybe easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding this: [Polymer 1.0 on firefox ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265769/polymer-1-0-on-firefox-referenceerror-polymer-is-not-defined)

I could resolve my problem:

Use `window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e){`  instead of

`HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {`

Like this:

```
var grid = grid || document.querySelector('vaadin-grid');
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function(e) {
  var json = '[["Blabla", true, "sdfsdfsd", "fsdsdfsdfsd fsdfds fsdf shfskd hds", 0, "39acbfa4-6d6b-4af9-b872-03fc70328183"]]';

  var testJSON = JSON.parse(json);
  grid.items = testJSON;

  grid.columns[0].renderer = function(cell) {
    //...
  };    
});
```